# Typdef from included file 'was not declared in this scope'

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a typedef that has been declared in an included header file, but I am getting the following error:

```
error: ‘Status’ was not declared in this scope
   Status status;
   ^
```

The typedef is declared in a header that is included in the file.

Server.hh (simplified):

```
class myClass {
   public:
      typedef mynamespace::Status Status;
      ...
}
```

ClientServer.cc:

```
#include "Server.hh"
...
Status status;  // error thrown here
```

Is there a problem with this approach? How can I make my typedef available across multiple files?

Comment: Looks like your typedef is inside a class.  If that is the case the name is scoped to the class, not the file.

Comment: the `public:` in front of the typedef indicates that the typedef is on a class scope so you might need `className::Status` to get the typedef, but thats pure guessing. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes you are correct. Moving the typedef outside of the class definition in Server.hh fixes the error. Thank you!

Comment: @user463035818 You should post your answer, as an answer, so it can be accepted

Comment: @NicholasPipitone its not an answer but just a guess into the blue. Also I dont agree that the question in its current state should be answered at all. It should be either fixed by adding the missing information (mcve) or closed

Comment: @user463035818 `public:` does indicate that it's in a class without ambiguity, I'll suggest an edit though.

Comment: @NathanOliver first provided the answer. Can you post as an answer please?

Comment: @tmath If I were you I would just delete the question.

Comment: I don't think the question warrants deletion, unless there's a shown duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typedef`, `using`, and `namespace`, are all local to the codeblock the statement was written in. You would have to reorganize `Server.hh` into

```
typedef mynamespace::Status Status;
class myClass {
   public:
      ...
}
```

for `Server.cc` to access it, as the `typedef` would then be in the outermost code block.

Comment: "local to the codeblock" is a bit misleading, maybe replace"codeblock" with "scope"... ( eg `namespace foo { typedef int bar;} namespace foo { bar x;}` are two blocks of code, but only one scope